# Kubernetes Deployment api apps/v1 - `selector` does not match template `labels`

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, containers, kubernetes-pod

We already have Deployment working but while we removing one of the labels from the Deployment, it's giving the following error:

```
The Deployment "nginx" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"app":"nginx", "replicaSetName":"nginx"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`
```

The older YAML file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: nginx
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: nginx
                policy: allow
        spec:
        .......
        ......
        ......
```

We want to remove `policy:allow` label from the deployment file. If we are removing we are facing an error.

Updated YAML file looks like following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: nginx
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: nginx
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: nginx
        spec:
        .......
        ......
        ......
```

Here we are not updating selector just updating the labels. It's showing an error.
To resolve this, we need to delete the deployment and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using api version: apps/v1,Check this section: [Label selector updates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#label-selector-updates)

> Note: In API version apps/v1, a Deployment's label selector is
> immutable after it gets created

Official docs say that you cannot edit the labels once you finish the deployment, Now you have to delete the deployment and re-apply the deployment with a key/value that works on your deployment. Additional info is that you can add the labels as the deployment works with the existing labels and run the new labels as well.

Comment: Here I am not updating the selectors. I am trying to update the labels in the template field. The selector is immutable but we can modify the labels for the pod template.

Comment: How are you editing the labels, are you using any command? If yes can you paste here..

Comment: I am not using any commands. I am updating it in the YAML file and redeploying it by kubectl apply.

Comment: After removing the label “policy: allow” follow the below  commands and try.  1. <kubectl delete deployment nginx>  2. <kubectl apply -f <<name.yaml>>

Comment: Yes, removing and recreating the deployment is working fine but that can cause downtime.